# It is possible to share content to specific social network without UIActivityViewController in iOS 13 and opens directly needed extension?

Tags: ios, swift, share, ios13, uiactivityviewcontroller

Our design team decided to use a custom layout for social sharing. For example, it will have 2 buttons on social networks (Telegram and Twitter for example). After deprecating a Social framework (iOS 11) is it possible to share directly to (Telegram for example)in iOS 13?

**I don't want to use UIActivityViewController. I need to open specific social extensions without UIActivityViewController!**

I have checked this:
[Social framework is deprecated in iOS11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52491654/social-framework-is-deprecated-in-ios11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do this with applications that support custom url schemas.

Some of them have official api, like [instagram](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/), some may have a private one that you can use as well, but at your own risk: the creators can remove or change this functionality; and some have none.

But you won't be able to create a post or message like you do in the `UIActivityViewController`, only to pass some data that the other application will somehow handle.